# Type hinting in php

Tags: php, oop, arguments, type-hinting

So I found this example, I'm learning php oop and I wanted to ask what is the meaning and what it does the argument ShopProduct in method addProduct?

```
abstract class ShopProductWriter {
    protected $products = array();
    public function addProduct( ShopProduct $shopProduct ) {
        $this->products[]=$shopProduct;
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP calls it [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

Comment: Please , do not reference assignments. It is both unnecessary and harmful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### lets take this line by line:

```
abstract class ShopProductWriter {
```

declares an `abstract` class named `ShopProductWriter`. `abstract` classes cannot be instantiated (you can never have an instance of `ShopProductWriter`.) In order to use this class you must create a class that extends `ShopProductWriter`. *see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php*

```
protected $products = array();
```

creates a class variable named `$products` that is an array. The visibility of this variable is `protected`. This means that `$products` can only be accessed from within class context using the this operator. Additionally, `$this->products` will be available to all classes extending `ShopProductWriter`. *see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php*

```
public function addProduct( ShopProduct $shopProduct ) {
```

defines a `public` visible function named `addProduct`, this function can be called outside class context on any class instance extending `ShopProductWriter`. This function takes a single paramater that must be an instance of `ShopProduct` OR a child class extending `ShopProduct` *("If class or interface is specified as type hint then all its children or implementations are allowed too." see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).*

```
$childInstance = new ChildCLassExtendingShopProductWriter();
$childInstance->addProduct($IAmAShopProductInstance);
```

lastly,

```
$this->products[]=$shopProduct;
```

the function adds whatever instance was passed into the addProduct function to the class array `products`.

Answer (score 4):

It means that `$shopProduct` must be an instance of `ShopProduct` class

But be aware that type hinting is possible only for objects, arrays and interfaces. You cannot do a type hint for a string, for example

You **cannot** do

`function wontWork(string $string) {}`

Comment: thank you :) i guess i understood the reason of using type hinting

Answer (score 1):

It adds the given product to the list of products stored by the object.

Answer (score 0):

`ShopProductWriter` is an abstract class. and `$products` is a protected variable where `array` stored 
`addProduct` is a function where list of product stored by the object